# get data from geonames using json

Tags: ajax, json, geonames

Im using this:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://api.geonames.org/searchJSON?username=presis',
        dataType: "jsonp",
        data: {
            name: city,
            countryName: country,
            maxRows: 1
        },
        jsonp: "jsonp",
        success: function(data) {
            $.map(data.geonames, function(item) {
                return {
                    value: item,
                };
            });
        }
    });
```

I just can't get it to work. What could the problem be?
In my chrome console i get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :" in the searchJSON object.

Comment: can show the json that is coming?

Comment: Have you found a solution for that?